# Session Start not being reset

Tags: google-analytics

We have had GA integrated within our app for several releases and, since our latest update, we noticed that all of our sessions are now showing a duration of 0.  We've traced this using the additional debug logging and found that it seems that setting:

```
[[self.class trackerForId:[obj trackingId]] set:kGAISessionControl value:@"start"];
```

does modify the 'sc' (session control) parameter in the hit, but that the change is sticky.  After we set this value and fire some Screen and Event hits, every hit is including 'sc=start'.  The data we're seeing in our sites shows that our iOS users has remained constant but our sessions have been multiplied by 6 or 7. Every single session running on the new version of GA is showing 0 duration as well.

Is it intended that this value needs to be manually reset?  When we run our old codebase, the start parameter is not sticky and only gets transmitted on the first hit.  The same non-sticky behavior is seen on Android. Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are sending the set:kGAISessionControl value:@"start" to the tracker. In v3, setting the session control directly on the tracker will continue sending session starts on all subsequent events.

Instead, create a single event for the start:

```
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:GA_EVENT_CATEGORY
                                                       action:GA_EVENT_ACTION
                                                        label:nil
                                                        value:nil] set:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl] build]];
```